# Applications will not launch and unable to back up after applying a software update

Tags: drivers, 18.04

I am having some serious issues after I applied software updates on my 18.04 LTS. I noticed serious issues right away after I did the restart and tried to launch Chrome. It was prompting me to put a password in (for the record I provide my password to log in (I do not have automatic login on)). Then I tried to launch other basic applications: terminal, file explorer and the apps simply won't launch. I said screw it let me just start off fresh (since I see 19.04 just came out not too long ago) but every time I try to upload a file it's saying it's going to take 100s of hours.

I do not have this issue on the Windows machines that I'm running, just this machine. I even did the same thing on the VirtualBox running on this broken 18.04 machine and the files uploaded within seconds. I am not sure what to do because I have files on this computer that I need so I cannot simply wipe it out. I tried plugging in a flash drive and it will not not let me open the file explorer app at all but it reads that my flash drive was plugged in and shows as mounted.

What might be causing this? I think it's related to this keychain thing; I already tried resetting my password and it did nothing.